# Как поменять цвет отдельно у переменных

Tags: python, json

Как поменять цвет для переменных и текста в VS Code? Я нашел вот такой код:

```
"editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations": {
    "enabled": false
},
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
        {
            "name": "variable",
            "scope": ["variable.other.readwrite"],
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#cc12bc"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Но не знаю как мне добавить еще новые цвета для других служебных слов. Можете как пример сделать отдельные цвета для условий,функций и переменных?
Например чтобы в def f(x) 'def','f','x' были разных цветов

Answer (score 0):

В settings.json пишем следующее(меняем на нужные цвета):

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "functions": "#81e172","comments": "#44b0f3","strings": "#da5c95","keywords": "#f85555"
    }
```